# How can I find a website has Id and token values?

Tags: javascript, html, token, html-parsing

Hello I am learning html parsing and I need the token value of a website but I didn't find for nearly 4 hours..I need it because of udemy course lesson. The site in the lesson was a pharmacy listing website but it broken now so I need to find new one.  Do you know any website which is I can see its id and token values in search bar? (for example id=123&token=123123345we3).
Note:Generally they are simple html websites..

Comment: "tokens" are usually short lived - perhaps you misunderstand the udemy lesson

Comment: There shouldn't be anything stopping you from adding query string values to a url, for instance take the url for this question.  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135382/how-can-i-find-a-website-has-id-and-token-values?id=me&token=you`